# How to be kept updated while traversing XML tree?

Tags: xml, dart, progress

How to be called when the `findAllElements()` traverses the whole tree, so that I get a chance to notify the user about progress?

```dart
 final document = XmlDocument.parse(xml);
 final pdvs = document
          .findAllElements('pdv');
```

Answer (score 1):

`findAllElements` returns a lazy `Iterable`, so it only searches for the next element once you request it (that is iterate over it). For example, with the following code each element is printed immediately as a new element is found and while the DOM tree is traversed:

```dart
for (final element in document.findAllElements('pdv')) {
  print(element);
}
```

If you want to have more frequent notifications while traversing over the other elements you could use something along the following code:

```dart
for (final element in document.descendantElements) {
  if (element.name.qualified == 'pdv') {
    print(element);
  } else {
    // update user about progress
  }
}
```

However, keep in mind that traversing the parsed nodes is quite efficient (unless you have many millions of nodes), the line `final document = XmlDocument.parse(xml);` is likely magnitudes slower than any of the examples above.